# Virtualenv intersection (python, django)

Tags: django, virtualenv, python-venv

When I did the command:

```
mkdir djangoproject
cd djangoproject/
python3 -m venv myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
echo Django~=2.0.6 > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
django-admin startproject projectname .
python manage.py runserver
```

I see the error at localhost:

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/

I did not create urls for "catalog" (used "catalog" in previous project)
I think that the issue deals with intersection of venvs. (I deleted previous project, but the error stayed)

How can I fix it?

```
Result of grep "catalog" -r .
```

> ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py: 
>   catalog has been loaded in the page
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   objects by merging their catalogs. It will construct an object for the
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   self._catalog = None
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> ## If a language doesn't have a catalog, use the Germanic default for ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> self._init_translation_catalog()
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   if self.__language == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE and self.domain ==
>   'django' and self._catalog is None:
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   if self._catalog is None:
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> ## No catalogs found for this language, set an empty catalog. ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> self._catalog = {}
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   def _init_translation_catalog(self):
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   """Create a base catalog using global django translations."""
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   """Merge another translation into this catalog."""
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   if not getattr(other, '_catalog', None):
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   return  # NullTranslations() has no _catalog
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   if self._catalog is None:
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> ## Take plural and _info from first catalog found (generally Django's). ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>
> self._catalog = other._catalog.copy()
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   self._catalog.update(other._catalog)
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:def
>   catalog():
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:
>   Return the current active catalog for further processing.
>   ./myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py:

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with virtualenvs? That error shows that you are visiting the /catalog URL in your browser.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because, when I am visiting default page ( http://127.0.0.1:8000)  I redirected to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/
But I did not create "catalog" url in my app. I created "catalog" url in the previous venv.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache or try in incognito mode.

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

Let's try creating it after deactivating your `venv`; you may also want to choose a fresh directory name other than `djangoproject`, in case you're not starting fresh:

```sh
deactivate
mkdir djangoproject
cd djangoproject/
python3 -m venv myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
echo Django==2.0.* > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
django-admin startproject projectname .
python manage.py runserver
```

Does that help?

Comment: It did not help. I still see **Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/**

Comment: Added grep "catalog" result fo the question